# Vanilla JS alternative to @submit.prevent="myMethod"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I use Vue.js for most of my JavaScript related stuff. However, I've come across a situation where I want to replicate some functionality that Vue achieves but in Vanilla JS.

Vue gives you this modifier you can put on a form element.

```
@submit.prevent="myMethod"
```

I want to do the same thing. I want the user to click a button, some JS code to happen and then for the form to be submitted.

This is one thing that I've already tried but the form submitted before the JS actually got executed.

```js
var form = document.getElementById('a-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
// my code
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's `preventDefault` function :

```
var form = document.getElementById('a-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
 event.preventDefault();

//code
});
```

Comment: Hmm, sorry I can't seem to get it working with `event.preventDefault();` added either. It still submits the form.

Comment: Found the reason it wasen't working. My script was inside the form element that I was trying to prevent from submitting. ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

Call `preventDefault` on the event in the submit event listener:

```js
let form = document.getElementById('theForm')
form.addEventListener('submit', (e)=> {
  console.log('event', e)
  console.log('default prevented', e.defaultPrevented)
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log('default prevented', e.defaultPrevented)
})
```

```html
<form id="theForm" action="#submitted">
<input name="theInput"/>
<button type="submit">Submit?</button>
</form>
```

Notice that this works even if the form is submitted by pressing enter.